# Ant jar command compile only files with extension .jar

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, jar

I wanna to make jar file of my project with Jenkins using Ant scripts, but my script compile from "src" folder only files with extension .jar, I wanna to compile all of these files to my jar, how to do that?

Folders structure at jenkins server:

```
+ /src
    + /net
        + /xxx          [there a lot of java classes]
    + plugin.yml
    + /resources
    + /structs
+ /lib                  [There is my java lib folder]
+ /build
+ build.xml
```

Ant script:

```
<project name="BCCore" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="net.xxx.core.BCCore"/>


<property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>




<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="classpath"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>       
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean-build,run"/>
```

When i am building my whole project using netbeans i get JAR file with weight ~4.0 MB, but weight of file builded with Ant on Jenkins server is about ~1.6 MB, when I looked at builded file from Jenkins (by JdGui) at folder has been only package "net.xxx.core. ..."

Comment: this has nothing to do with jenkins.  Did you try ant from command line?

Comment: I just added Build Action "Invoke Ant" with no parameters in Jenkins (when I run script from command line result has been same like by Jenkins), and there is executed default "main" target, so all I think is good, because Jar is building, but worries me that builded jar is half time less weight and inside of that jar are **only** files with extension **.java**, and there should be other files like "plugin.yml, /resources ..." I probably missed something in script I think

Answer (score 0):

I found code which helped me to do what i want:

```
<copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</copy>
```

I added it to target "compile":

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="classpath"/>
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```